# The name 'movieGenre' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I write a ASP.NET MVC 3 project for service a video store. I add a CRUD MovieController class and add a search feature in it. But I receive an error: "The name 'movieGenre' does not exist in the current context" for the method. Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
{
    var GenreList = new List<string>();
    var GenreQuery = from d in db.Movies
                     orderby d.Genre
                     select d.Genre;
    GenreList.AddRange(GenreQuery.Distinct());
    ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreList);

    var movies = from m in db.Movies select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.movieGenre))
    {
        return View(movies);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre));
    }

    return View(movies);
}
```

For the last movieGenre I'm receiving this error.

Comment: There is never a reason to write `from x in y select x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do use a select list you have to use ViewData instead of a ViewBag.

```
 ViewData["Genre"] = new SelectList(GenreList);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `movieGenre` variable.

You mean `ViewBag.movieGenre`.

Comment: If I write ViewBag.movieGenre instead of movieGenre I'm getting an error: "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation".

Comment: When I run it I'm geting an error: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'movieGenre'".

Comment: You can't use the `dynamic` ViewBag in a LINQ query.  You should use a variable instead of ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in method declaration.
You have:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
```

Should be:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string movieGenre, string searchString)
```